# Android Retrofit encode URL

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using retrofit 2 and when I want to call a url like base/first/second
slashes are converted into %2F 
According to retrofit official document I should be able to use

(@Path(value = "address" , encode = false)

but Android studio says :
   cannot find symbol method encode()

Answer (score 6):

Try -

`encoded=false`.   Not `encode=false`

Answer (score 3):

Yes I had this problem from retrofit and I solved it with that:

**Shortly, your answer is:** `(@Path(value ="address", encode = false) String address)`

For example our link is: https://mobile.test/android

**Firts off all, your Builder want to have an *setEndpoint()*. You can give "http:/" or "https:/" .**

```
RestAdapter.Builder restBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://")
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));
    return restBuilder.build();
```

**Secondly, you should give your String value to @GET("/{address}"):**

```
@GET("/{address}") void getExampleModels(@Path(value = "address", encode = false) String address, Callback<exampleModel> callback);
```

**Finally, you can call it with String parameter without your error:**

```
getYourClass().getExampleModels(
            "mobile.test/android",
            newCallback<exampleModel>(){ 
                . . . 
            });
```

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

What Emma said, but actually `encoded=true` not false.